# Python: Creating a list of pairs using list comprehensions? What's the syntax?

Tags: python, django

While I am working with some models I created in Django (a web dev framework that uses Python), I think that this question is mostly a python question.

Check these lines of code.

```
sorted_greek_books=sorted(BookTitlesGreek.objects.all(),key=lambda book: (book.book_type,book.title_of_book))
booklist_greek= [book.title_of_book
   for book in sorted_greek_books]
```

For each book in booklist_greek, I would like the book title to be paired with the book type. Is this possible? What is the syntax for that?

I took a guess (albeit for the latin books on my website, but the lines of code are written in the exact same structure). But I don't have an easy way to actually test this, since it requires connection to my database and django and some other backend components. Here's my guess:

```
def IndexView(request):
    sorted_latin_books=sorted(BookTitles.objects.all(),key=lambda book: (book.book_type,book.title_of_book))
    booklist_latin= [(book.title_of_book, book.book_type)
            for book in sorted_latin_books, for book in sorted_latin_books]
```

So if this could yield something like...

[("Textbook Title", "textbook"), ("List Title", list) ... ] then that would be my goal.

Is this possible? Does anyone know the syntax? Also if you're going to link a really basic documentation that has you thinking "wow how did OP not read this he shouldn't be programming what a fool" please send the documentation because I really am getting used to django and javascript.

Comment: `booklist_latin= [(book.title_of_book, book.book_type)
            for book in sorted_latin_books]` that should suffice.

Comment: Not any of my business, but you might want to try to figure out how to make testing as easy as possible. This might not be the only time you're not100% sure about your code ;)

Comment: Of course! There's one person in particular I'm working with who knows enough about python and django so that they would be able to help me perform testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
booklist_latin= [(book.title_of_book, book.book_type) for book in sorted_latin_books]
```

Ref: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python